# Installing Samsung Xpress M2825DW drivers on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, printing, kubuntu, samsung

I'm having trouble with installing printer drivers. I tried to find them in the data base and could not find them. So I downloaded the linux drivers from samsung.com (http://www.samsung.com/de/support/model/SL-M2825DW/SEE-downloads#) and then used the .ppd-file. The error message was: Package missing: "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl".

Where can I find this package?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I can find the file rastertospl under the directory (in my case /opt/Samsung/)**uld/arm/** after extracting the driver package V1.00.06
downloaded from http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/SL-M2825DW/XAA-downloads?downloadName=DR
There is also an i386 version under ../i386/